# scipy's splrep/splev for python interpolation returns nan

Tags: python, scipy, nan

I have a [data set](http://users-phys.au.dk/daniel89/test.txt) with the first column is the `x` data (wavelenght) and the second column is the `y` data (relative intensity).

I wish to interpolate it on to another `x_new`-data but my problem is that `splrep` returns `nan`-values:

```
>>import numpy as np
>>from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
>>d = np.loadtxt("test.txt")
>>x,y = d[:,0],d[:,1]
>>
>>f = splrep( x,y,k=5 )
>>print f
>>(array([ 4501.19,  4501.19,  4501.19, ...,  7091.74,  7091.74,  7091.74]), array([ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]), 5)
```

It also happens when I don't specify `k`. Any suggestions how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `x` values probably contain duplicates, use `s=...` keyword argument to splrep to set a smoothing factor, because if this is not set the splines are supposed to go through every point *exactly* which is impossible with duplicates.

It might be that they are not duplicates but just very close too.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I didn't know that. It turns out that it was easier just to remove the duplicates.